# Codechef PERMUT2 solution

Tags: algorithm

Following website has the problem.

http://www.codechef.com/problems/PERMUT2

I have been trying to code solution for PERMUT2. My below solution is failing on some test cases. Kindly help me uncover flaws in the below code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[100000];

int main()
{
    int i, j, n, ret;
    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if(n == 0)
            break;
        ret = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
            scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if(a[i] != i + 1)
                ret++;
        if(ret % 2 == 0)
            printf("ambiguous\n");
        else
            printf("not ambiguous\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what ``res`` is counting : why do you check ``a[i] != i + 1``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not checking the right property. `if(a[i] != i + 1) ret++;` is not the right checking.

You want to check `a[a[i] - 1] == i + 1` for all elements on the array:

```
bool ambiguous = true;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (a[a[i] - 1] != i + 1) {
        ambiguous = false; 
        break;
    }
}
if(ambiguous)
    printf("ambiguous\n");
else
    printf("not ambiguous\n");
```